# Multiple color styles in one GeoServer layer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, style, sld, mapping

I have a GeoServer layer coming from a shapefile and I am using it with OpenLayers. I want to put multiple colors in the same layer depending on their attributes. How can I put multiple colors on a GeoServer layer depending on the attributes of the layer?

The result I want is something like this:

[image: styled layer example]

The only thing I've tried is to create a style in GeoServer and add it to the layer, but I don't know how to add multiple styles depending on the attributes of the layer.

The code of my layer style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- a Named Layer is the basic building block of an SLD document -->
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>poligono_rojo_verde</Name>
    <UserStyle>
    <!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
      <Title>poligono_rojo_verde</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample style that draws a polygon</Abstract>
      <!-- FeatureTypeStyles describe how to render different features -->
      <!-- A FeatureTypeStyle for rendering polygons -->
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <Title>Gray Polygon with Black Outline</Title>
          <Abstract>A polygon with a gray fill and a 1 pixel black outline</Abstract>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill"> #ff0000 </CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#0cff00</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: do you mean something like https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/lines.html#attribute-based-line

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, I just updated the question with what I tried to make it work. I will study your answer to find a solution, thanks again !!! :)

Comment: Thanks Ian Turton your response is the solution for my question!!!